# Sidebar navigation with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a navigation to the left of my page. this navigation should have the full height of the page.

I tried to build it with the Bootstrap grid system. But in this case, the navigation grows to much in width. Even if I use only `col-1` for the navigation sidebar.

This is what I want to build:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was sure that there was a thing for this, but it appears as though
I was incorrect (however if you found it please let me know).

I added two classes `.col-sm-fixed` which sets the width to be the same as 1 column width, but gives it a `max-width` and `min-width` for readability.

The other is `.flex-auto` which just sets the sets the properties of the `flex` value so that no matter how big, this item will grow to fill the space for the row. Also, I added a `flex-nowrap` (from bootstrap) to the row to keep any shenanigans happening where the main content could be pushed off.

## edit

I found the bootstrap equivalent of `flex-auto`, which is `col`.

[link here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width)

```css
.col-sm-fixed {
  flex: 0 0 8.333%;
  max-width: 250px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.flex-auto {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  min-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row flex-nowrap">
    <div class="col bg-info">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active">Hi</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Howdy</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-11 pl-1 bg-warning">
      Main Content Here?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```